# select values or NULL if it does not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, mariadb

I have a table `user` with columns `id` (primary key) and `name` (unique constraint) containing:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | u1   |
| 2  | u2   |
| 3  | u3   |
+----+------+
```

I would like a make a query, something like `SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE name IN (?,?)`, with parameters `("u2", "u4")`, that I can reuse in CTE, but which returns:

```
+------+------+
|  id  | name |
+------+------+
| 2    | u2   |
| NULL | u4   |
+------+------+
```

(edit: s/NULL/u4).

Is it possible? I'm interested in MariaDB and PostgreSQL.

One use case would be to insert the `id`s result in another table where `NULL` is not accepted, so it would insert the `name`s and check for invalid values in only 1 request. (no need for 2 separates requests + application code).

Comment: It feels like a temp table with a LEFT OUTER JOIN to this `user` table would be the most appropriate route here. A CTE solution would be like `WITH mycte AS (SELECT 'u2' as user UNION ALL SELECT 'u4') SELECT user.* FROM mycte LEFT OUTER JOIN user On mycte.user = user.name` (YMMV depending on RDBMS and what is allowed).

Comment: Why do you want NULL in the results for the column `name`?

Comment: @forpas you're right, it shoud be u4 instead of NULL. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @JNevill seems to be the good answer! (I'll have to adapt the `JOIN` as I edited the question)... The syntax of "inputing" the parameters is verbose, but it works

Comment: If the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` isn't needed since a `NULL` row doesn't need to be returned, then there is no reason for all of this complication. Just do `SELECT * FROM user WHERE name IN ('U2','U4')`. This is straightforward and also makes it so you can properly parameterize your query if you are doing this in an application outside of a sql client (to avoid a sql injection attack).

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways.. An easy one in Postgresql could be:

```
select a, "name"
from unnest(ARRAY['u2', 'u4']::text[]) AS a
LEFT JOIN "user" AS u ON a = u."name";
```

Comment: Thanks! Planning to switch from MariaDB to PostgreSQL, so it give a good example of how a achieve things differenlty

Comment: Note that `unnest(ARRAY['u2', 'u4']::text[])` can also be written in a SQL standard compliant way: `values ('u2'), ('u4')`